# How to change spacing between axis label and ticks labels with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, spacing

This seems a very basic question but I can't find the answer: how to change the default spacing between the axis main label and the axis ticks label? I have looked through `theme` documentation but could find only the `axis.ticks.margin` option which lets set the spacing between ticks and ticks label.

For example,

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = seq(from=1, l = 5))
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_line()
```

produces the following:

[image: example]

where I'd like to add more space between the label `y` and the axis (`y` and `3` are too close for me).

Comment: `theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(r=10)))`

Comment: I got an error `Error in element_text(margin = margin(r = 10)) : 
  unused argument (margin = margin(r = 10))` Is there another package I should load ?

Comment: Works for me. What version of ggplot are you using? If < 2.1.0, update.

Comment: ok I am `ggplot2_1.0.1` I am going to do as you say

Comment: works perfectly thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can try this as well

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = seq(from=1, l = 5))
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_line()+
    ylab("y\n\n")
```

Comment: this may not be the proper way to do this but definitely a good trick I think !

Comment: See [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/WDCGoHOZdNY) and [here](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1435).